# How to display up/down arrow when clicking on HTML Table Columns for Sorting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page I have a html dynamic table which is filled by an ajax post call. On that table I want to sort values column wise on_click of the column headings. Which is also working fine using the shared code below.

Now, I want to display small icons mentioned below (fontawesome icons) just beside the column name when clicked. If the column is not clicked for sorting the icon should not show. In my javascript code, makeAllSortable() should be called on windows load and on 1st click on any column will show the values in asc order and on 2nd click it will be on desc order.

Icons:

```
<i class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>  - for ascending order
<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>  - for descending order
```

Javascript Code:

```
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}


function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () { sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir)) });
    }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}
```

I am not getting any way out. Please help.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: https://datatables.net/

Comment: And the problem is? In the `click` handler you already have the sort order (`dir = 1 - dir`). Instead of only calling `sortTable()` grab the `<i>` element and set the class according to the sort order. And you don't even have to check the visibility. Just always call `.show()`.

Comment: Also wondering what the problem is.   `table.tHead[0].rows[0].cells[i]` then show/hide the up/down icon.  Or, in jquery click event handler `$(".fa", this).hide();$(".fa-caret-up", this).show(dir);$(".fa-caret-down", this).show(!dir)`  (or whichever way works for your `dir`)

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. But as its a dynamic table, I have to have the <i> element there in the html so that I can add the required class there but no chance to add that element while the html table is populating.

Comment: @freedomn-m can you please send any fiddle or so?

Comment: Even if this would be a problem, my approach assumes that there is already (at least) one `<i>` element

Comment: *"As it's a dynamic table..[can't] add `<i>` to the table"* - I guess we have different meaning for "dynamic table" then as I can't see why you can't add it as the table is generated.  Even so, it's not hard to add in the js `$("<i class='fa fa-caret-up"></i>").appendTo(this)`.  Perhaps I'm (we're) overestimating your ability, based on the (overly complicated) code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

sample code ...

```js
const sortOrder = document.getElementById('sort-order')

function changeOrder(evt)
  {
  this.className = (this.className==='')? 'upOrder' : (this.className==='upOrder') ? 'downOrder' : ''
  }


sortOrder.addEventListener('click',changeOrder )
```

```css
#sort-order {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0 7px;
}
#sort-order > i { display:none; }
#sort-order.upOrder   > i.fa-caret-up   { display:inline; }
#sort-order.downOrder > i.fa-caret-down { display:inline; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" />

<div id="sort-order">
  <i class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>  
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
</div>

<-- click in!
```